# How to get off transparency of my imageView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-yosemite

I am using an ImageView.
Having a picture inside, working well as aspected with 10.9 sdk.
    [_myImageView setImage:myImage];

Since 10.10 sdk the picture has transparency. (10.11 too)

Has anyone a hint of the common way to get the transparency out of the picture?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post screen captures of the before and after images?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/00H2j.png I dont know, if this works.

I pasted one picture into the other. The middle small bright part has transparency from a white window below the picture.

All this occours since sdk 10.10.
Before over years no problems.

In addition, in 10.10 sdk the border-style of the view has effect on transparency.
If I set in interface builder the border-style (usually "bezel") to "none", the transparency gets off.

Any ideas?
Thanks whxde